# Accurately count number of keywords "if", "while" in a c file

Tags: c, compiler-construction, code-coverage, static-analysis

Are there any libraries out there that I can pass my .c files through and will count the visible number of, of example, "if" statements?

We don't have to worry about "if" statement in other files called by the current file, just count of the current file.

I can do a simple grep or regex but wanted to check if there is something better (but still simple)

Comment: How do you want the solution to be better than something involving `grep` and `wc -l`? What additional metrics would you like?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is something like the equivalent of DOM for c. Instead of parsing myself and hoping my parsing is accurate, the compiler already knows how to parse c code. So why can't I ask a parser for that instead?

Comment: Well, firstly you should think of AST (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) rather than DOM for this particular domain. I found a reference to a tool called cccc here - http://cysquatch.net/blog/?p=54 - This tool measures (among other things) cyclomatic complexity, which is a measurement of the amount of branching in source code. For more info on that, see this link - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CyclomaticComplexityMetric

Comment: You don't need an AST for this.  Producing lexemes and counting them will solve OP's problem just fine.   You could lift the lexer for any C compiler (e.g., GCC) and pretty easily adjust it to count all the keywords of each type.    If you don't use a fully accurate lexer, (eg., you decide to use grep) you'll get bogus hits in text strings and comments.   So the only question is, how important is a deadly accurate count?

Comment: OP is a little unclear on what he really wants; his comments suggests he wants a "DOM" at which point an AST is the right answer. (I'm not sure CCCC builds an AST).

Comment: Thanks! A lots of good stuff, clang with -ast-dump-xml looks exactly what I wanted and I can parse the model to count number of "if" statements. cccc tool looks cool but it doesn't compile on a mac so I have to do some work on compile it. TCL looks very promising as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure it's done right, I'd probably make use of clang and walk the ast. A URL to get you started:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no way to use regular expressions or grep to give you the correct answer you are looking for.  There are lots of ways that you would find those strings, but they could be buried in any amount of escape characters, quotations, comments, etc.

As some commenters have stated, you will need to use a parser/lexer that understands the C language.  You want something simple, you said, so you won't be writing this yourself :)

This seems like it might be usable for you:

http://wiki.tcl.tk/3891

From the page:

> lexes a string containing C source into a list of tokens

That will probably get you what you want, but even then it's not going to be trivial.

Answer (score -1):

What everyone has said so far is correct; it seems a lot easier to just grep the shit out of your file.  The performance hit of this is neglagible compared to the alternative which is to go get the gcc source code (or whichever compiler you're using), and then go through the parsing code and hook in what you want to do while it parses the syntax tree.  This seems like a pain in the ass, especially when all you're worried about is the conditional statements.  If you actually care about the branches, you could actually just take a look at the object code and count the number of if statements in the assembly, which would correctly tell you the number of branches (rather than just relying on how many times you typed a conditional, which will not translate exactly to the branching of the program).

Comment: The "number of branches" in the object code doesn't match your source very well, either for several reasons:  a) the compiler may optimize away conditionals where legal, b) it may generate multiple conditionals to implement what you think of as a single conditional, c) just becuase you found some hex bytes that appear to be branch, doesn't mean they are; they might just be funny looking data.

Comment: Exactly, thats why it doesn't make much sense to even try and count the if statements inside the source code.

Comment: OP gives us no clue as to why he is counting statements, so I don't see how you can jump to this conclusion.   In the absence of a reason, one can surmise he is interested in code complexity, at which point the conditionals in the source code are exactly what he should want.  "code complexity" is trying to get at how difficult a program is to *understand*, not what it looks like when it is compiled.    Your point about counting branches by looking in the object code makes far less sense; a key reason is that you can't easily know whether bytes that look like a conditional branch in fact are.